# How to get XML values

Tags: magento-1.9, php, api, xml

I'm using an API to send a request to a webservice, and it returns me an XML, but I don't know how to read the XML values

Here is my code:

```
    $url = 'http://urlexample';

    $headers = array(
        "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Accept: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    );

    $method = 'GET';

    $connection = new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl();

    if ($method == "GET") {
        $zendMethod = Zend_Http_Client::GET;
    } elseif ($method == "POST") {
        $zendMethod = Zend_Http_Client::POST;
    } elseif ($method == "PUT") {
        $zendMethod = Zend_Http_Client::PUT;            
        $connection->addOption(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        $connection->addOption(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
    }

    $connection->setConfig(
        array(
        'timeout'   => 30
        )
    );

    $connection->write($zendMethod, $url, '1.0', $headers, $body);
    $response = $connection->read();
    $connection->close();

    $httpCode = Zend_Http_Response::extractCode($response);
    $response = Zend_Http_Response::extractBody($response);


    echo "<textarea>" . $response . "</textarea>" ;
```

The xml it returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataSet xmlns="http://">
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns=""     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="Produtos">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="TIMESTAMP" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="DEPARTAMENTO" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="CATEGORIA" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="SUBCATEGORIA" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="FABRICANTE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="CODIGO" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="DESCRICAO" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="DESCRTEC" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="PARTNUMBER" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="EAN" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="GARANTIA" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="PESOKG" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="PRECOREVENDA" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="PRECOSEMST" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="DATAVALIDADEPRECO" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="DISPONIVEL" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="URLFOTOPRODUTO" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="ESTOQUE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="NCM" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="LARGURA" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="ALTURA" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="PROFUNDIDADE" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="ATIVO" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="SUBSTTRIBUTARIA" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="ORIGEMPRODUTO" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="ESTOQUEDISPONIVEL" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <NewDataSet xmlns="">
        <Produtos diffgr:id="Produtos1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                <TIMESTAMP>2017-08-11T11:09:26-03:00</TIMESTAMP>
                <DEPARTAMENTO></DEPARTAMENTO>
                <CATEGORIA></CATEGORIA>
                <SUBCATEGORIA></SUBCATEGORIA>
                <FABRICANTE>GENIUS</FABRICANTE>
                <CODIGO>0064703</CODIGO>
                <DESCRICAO></DESCRICAO>
                <DESCRTEC></DESCRTEC>
                <PARTNUMBER>31731047103</PARTNUMBER>
                <EAN>4710268244738</EAN>
                <GARANTIA>12</GARANTIA>
                <PESOKG>3.1000</PESOKG>
                <PRECOREVENDA>95.0000</PRECOREVENDA>
                <PRECOSEMST>95.0000</PRECOSEMST>
                <DATAVALIDADEPRECO></DATAVALIDADEPRECO>
                <DISPONIVEL>1</DISPONIVEL>
                <URLFOTOPRODUTO></URLFOTOPRODUTO>
                <ESTOQUE>RJ</ESTOQUE>
                <NCM></NCM>
                <LARGURA>0.3000</LARGURA>
                <ALTURA>0.3500</ALTURA>
                <PROFUNDIDADE>0.1700</PROFUNDIDADE>
                <ATIVO>1</ATIVO>
                <SUBSTTRIBUTARIA>0</SUBSTTRIBUTARIA>
                <ORIGEMPRODUTO></ORIGEMPRODUTO>
                <ESTOQUEDISPONIVEL>63.0000</ESTOQUEDISPONIVEL>
            </Produtos>
            <Produtos diffgr:id="Produtos2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
                <TIMESTAMP>2017-08-14T18:01:00-03:00</TIMESTAMP>
                <DEPARTAMENTO></DEPARTAMENTO>
                <CATEGORIA></CATEGORIA>
                <SUBCATEGORIA></SUBCATEGORIA>
                <FABRICANTE>GENIUS</FABRICANTE>
                <CODIGO>0064694</CODIGO>
                <DESCRICAO></DESCRICAO>
                <DESCRTEC></DESCRTEC>
                <PARTNUMBER>31731006100</PARTNUMBER>
                <EAN>4710268238461</EAN>
                <GARANTIA>12</GARANTIA>
                <PESOKG>0.4900</PESOKG>
                <PRECOREVENDA>28.9900</PRECOREVENDA>
                <PRECOSEMST>28.9900</PRECOSEMST>
                <DATAVALIDADEPRECO></DATAVALIDADEPRECO>
                <DISPONIVEL>1</DISPONIVEL>
                <URLFOTOPRODUTO></URLFOTOPRODUTO>
                <ESTOQUE>RJ</ESTOQUE>
                <NCM>85182100            </NCM>
                <LARGURA>0.1500</LARGURA>
                <ALTURA>0.1200</ALTURA>
                <PROFUNDIDADE>0.0700</PROFUNDIDADE>
                <ATIVO>1</ATIVO>
                <SUBSTTRIBUTARIA>0</SUBSTTRIBUTARIA>
                <ORIGEMPRODUTO></ORIGEMPRODUTO>
                <ESTOQUEDISPONIVEL>100.0000</ESTOQUEDISPONIVEL>
            </Produtos>
        </NewDataSet>
    </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

The echo in the last was just so I could see the xml, it works but I don't know how to read it. It shows a list of products and attributes. 
I have tried with SimpleXML but I wasn't successful

Edit: Just realized I should have posted it in PHP session instead of Magento hehehe
sorry

Comment: Shouldn't this non-Magento-specific question be on Stack Overflow instead?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [SimpleXMLElements](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) instead.
Just initiate it with `$xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($response);` and dump that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) which will interpret a string of XML into an object.

**Example**

```
$response="<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>";

$xml= simplexml_load_string($response);
```

You can also convert your Object to array by combining `json_encode` and `json_decode`

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($response);
print_r(json_decode(json_encode($xml), true)); // Will return you array
```

Comment: That returns a blank array, "Array ( )". Shouldn't I be able to see the values?

Comment: The above example gives me the result. You can paste your xml response.

Comment: @Priyank My soap return as Object, how can i return as XML?

Answer (score 1):

if I understand you right, you want to read the values of your xml response. Here is a full documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php);

And then you can use it as object.

For example you have this response:

```
$response = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<document>
 <title>Forty What?</title>
 <from>Joe</from>
 <to>Jane</to>
 <body>
  I know that's the answer -- but what's the question?
 </body>
</document>
XML;
```

You need to make this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
```

And then if you need value of `<title>` write this code: `$title = $xml->title;`.

If your xml response looks like this:

```
<config>
    <data>
        <value1>somevalue</value1>
        <value2>somevalue</value2>
        <value3>somevalue</value3>
        <value4>somevalue</value4>
   </data>
</config>
```

And you need to get value of `<value1>`, just make this construction `$value1 = $xml->data->value1;`.

If something isn't clear, ask me in comments to my answer

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply! I add this to end of code $response = simplexml_load_string($response);
        print_r($response);  and it shows object(SimpleXMLElement)#22 (0) { }, is it correct? Or should return something else

Comment: @Stordon , yes. If you want to look on it as on object use `var_dump($response);`

Comment: using var_dump it shows me a blank page. I'm gonna edit my post with the XML it returns

Comment: Maybe your server blocks var_dump, try to `var_dump('test');` and say what you see

Comment: It shows string(4) "test". I edited my post with my xml

Comment: @Stordon , I sow your output. It is actually XSD. Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756254/parse-xsd-file-in-php-and-display-the-elements-in-the-xsd

Comment: Oh, ok. I didn't even know what the code was, thats great. Thanks, but that link didn't help me at all

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following method which magento 2.4 used inside its core modules.

```
 $xml = new \Magento\Framework\Simplexml\Config();
        $xml->loadString($xmlResponse);
        $arr = $xml->getXpath("//DataSet/NewDataSet/Produtos/text()");
```

Comment: If you convert this code example to DI then I'll happily upvote it.